# How do I convert DateTime from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to yyyymmddThhmmssZ in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert a given date and time in format ( yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss ) to (yyyymmddThhmmssZ) in php. For example: 2020-07-30 18:30:00 should be 20200730T183000Z. I also want to know if there are any existing/in-built methods to accomplish this?

Comment: ha. the clue is already in one of your tags. php's `DateTime`

Comment: Have you made any effort at all to solve this problem yourself yet?

Comment: I want to know if there are any existing methods to perform this

Comment: yep, there are existing methods to perform this [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in your comments, you can simply do this with the `DateTime` object

Here's an example:

```php
$date = '2020-07-21 18:50:32';
$obj = new \DateTime('@' . strtotime($date));
echo $obj->format(DATE_RFC3339); // 2020-07-22T01:50:32+00:00
```

If RFC3339 isn't your preferred format, feel free to pick one from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.types), or [build your own](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Try it out: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3246477b676e17022da799697acf4df375e1fe08

Comment: this clarified it.